Subject: Not able to receive data in my C/C++ UDP receiver code from sender using custom DPDK application in C/C++
Scenario 1: A simple C/C++ application sends data from one Linux PC to another PC running a simple C/C++ receiver application.
Result: Sender is able to send and receiver is able to receive data.
Scenario 2: A custom DPDK application in C/C++ sends data from one Linux PC to another PC running a simple C/C++ receiver application.
Result: Sender is able to send, but receiver is not able to receive the data.
Note: To verify from the sender side, we checked data in Wireshark. Data from the custom DPDK sender is received at Wireshark.
When we say simple C/C++ application, it means without using DPDK.
Kindly let me know what could be the issue at receiver side or sender side when we use DPDK based application.
For your refernce, i attached both code & wireshark captured packet image
UDP_DPDK_send application

// UDP_DPDK_send
#include <rte_common.h>
#include <rte_eal.h>
#include <rte_mbuf.h>
#include <rte_ether.h>
#include <rte_ip.h>
#include <rte_udp.h>
#include <rte_ethdev.h>
#include <rte_malloc.h>
#include <rte_log.h>
#include <rte_ether.h>
#include <rte_mbuf.h>
#include <rte_cycles.h>
#include <rte_timer.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <stdint.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>  

#define NUM_MBUFS 8192
#define MBUF_CACHE_SIZE 250
#define BURST_SIZE 32

#define JUMBO_FRAME_MAX_SIZE    0x2600

#define MAX_PORTS 16

#define MCAST_CLONE_PORTS   2
#define MCAST_CLONE_SEGS    2

#define PKT_MBUF_DATA_SIZE  RTE_MBUF_DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE
#define NB_PKT_MBUF 8192

#define HDR_MBUF_DATA_SIZE  (2 * RTE_PKTMBUF_HEADROOM)
#define NB_HDR_MBUF (NB_PKT_MBUF * MAX_PORTS)

#define NB_CLONE_MBUF   (NB_PKT_MBUF * MCAST_CLONE_PORTS * MCAST_CLONE_SEGS * 2)


static const struct rte_eth_conf port_conf_default = {
        .rxmode = {
                .mtu = JUMBO_FRAME_MAX_SIZE - RTE_ETHER_HDR_LEN -
                RTE_ETHER_CRC_LEN,
                .split_hdr_size = 0,
        },
        .txmode = {
                .mq_mode = RTE_ETH_MQ_TX_NONE,
                .offloads = RTE_ETH_TX_OFFLOAD_MULTI_SEGS,
        },
};


// Helper function to compute checksum
    
uint16_t compute_checksum(const void *data, size_t len) {
    const uint16_t *buf = (uint16_t *)data;
    uint32_t sum = 0;
    while (len > 1) {
        sum += *buf++;
        len -= 2;
    }
    if (len) {
        sum += *(uint8_t *)buf;
    }
    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xFFFF);
    sum += (sum >> 16);
    return (uint16_t)~sum;
}

// Function to compute UDP checksum
uint16_t calculate_udp_checksum(struct rte_ipv4_hdr *ip_hdr, struct rte_udp_hdr *udp_hdr, uint8_t *payload, uint16_t payload_len) {
    struct pseudo_header {
        uint32_t src_addr;
        uint32_t dst_addr;
        uint8_t placeholder;
        uint8_t protocol;
        uint16_t udp_length;
    } __attribute__((packed));

    struct pseudo_header psh;
    psh.src_addr = ip_hdr->src_addr;
    psh.dst_addr = ip_hdr->dst_addr;
    psh.placeholder = 0;
    psh.protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;
    psh.udp_length = udp_hdr->dgram_len;

    size_t psh_len = sizeof(psh);
    size_t udp_len = sizeof(struct rte_udp_hdr) + payload_len;

    // Compute checksum of the pseudo-header + UDP header + payload
    uint16_t checksum = compute_checksum(&psh, psh_len);
    checksum = compute_checksum(&checksum, sizeof(checksum)); // checksum of pseudo-header

    checksum = compute_checksum(udp_hdr, udp_len);
    checksum = compute_checksum(payload, payload_len);

    return checksum;
}

// Function to compute IP header checksum
uint16_t calculate_ip_checksum(struct rte_ipv4_hdr *ip_hdr) {
    ip_hdr->hdr_checksum = 0; // Set to 0 before calculation
    return compute_checksum(ip_hdr, sizeof(struct rte_ipv4_hdr));
}


void send_udp_packet(uint16_t port_id, const char *dst_ip, uint16_t dst_port) {

    struct rte_mbuf *mbuf;
    struct rte_ether_hdr *eth_hdr;
    struct rte_ipv4_hdr *ip_hdr;
    struct rte_udp_hdr *udp_hdr;
    uint8_t *payload;
    uint16_t payload_len = 100; // Example payload length

    mbuf = rte_pktmbuf_alloc(rte_pktmbuf_pool_create("TX_POOL", NUM_MBUFS, MBUF_CACHE_SIZE, 0, RTE_MBUF_DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE, rte_socket_id()));
    if (mbuf == NULL) {
        rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Failed to allocate mbuf\n");
    }

    eth_hdr = rte_pktmbuf_mtod(mbuf, struct rte_ether_hdr *);
    ip_hdr = (struct rte_ipv4_hdr *)(eth_hdr + 1);
    udp_hdr = (struct rte_udp_hdr *)(ip_hdr + 1);
    payload = (uint8_t *)(udp_hdr + 1);

    // Fill in Ethernet header
    struct rte_ether_addr src_addr = { { 0x6C, 0xB3, 0x11, 0x68, 0x9E, 0x96 } }; // Source MAC address
    struct rte_ether_addr dst_addr = { { 0x4C, 0xD7, 0x17, 0xA8, 0x17, 0x0B } }; // Destination MAC address
    rte_ether_addr_copy(&src_addr, &eth_hdr->src_addr);
    rte_ether_addr_copy(&dst_addr, &eth_hdr->dst_addr);
    eth_hdr->ether_type = rte_cpu_to_be_16(RTE_ETHER_TYPE_IPV4);

    // Fill in IPv4 header
    ip_hdr->version_ihl = (4 << 4) | 5; // Version 4, IHL 5
    ip_hdr->type_of_service = 0;
    ip_hdr->total_length = rte_cpu_to_be_16(sizeof(struct rte_ipv4_hdr) + sizeof(struct rte_udp_hdr) + payload_len);
    ip_hdr->packet_id = rte_cpu_to_be_16(1);
    ip_hdr->fragment_offset = rte_cpu_to_be_16(0x4000);//rte_cpu_to_be_16(0);
    ip_hdr->time_to_live = 64;
    ip_hdr->next_proto_id = IPPROTO_UDP;
    ip_hdr->src_addr = rte_cpu_to_be_32(inet_addr("192.168.1.103")); // Source IP address
    ip_hdr->dst_addr = rte_cpu_to_be_32(inet_addr(dst_ip)); // Destination IP address

    // Fill in UDP header
    udp_hdr->src_port = rte_cpu_to_be_16(48842); // Source port
    udp_hdr->dst_port = rte_cpu_to_be_16(dst_port); // Destination port
    udp_hdr->dgram_len = rte_cpu_to_be_16(sizeof(struct rte_udp_hdr) + payload_len);
    udp_hdr->dgram_cksum = 0; // Placeholder, will be computed later

    // Fill in payload
    memset(payload, 'A', payload_len);

    // Calculate checksums
    ip_hdr->hdr_checksum = calculate_ip_checksum(ip_hdr);
    udp_hdr->dgram_cksum = calculate_udp_checksum(ip_hdr, udp_hdr, payload, payload_len);

    // Set mbuf data length
    mbuf->data_len = sizeof(struct rte_ether_hdr) + sizeof(struct rte_ipv4_hdr) + sizeof(struct rte_udp_hdr) + payload_len;
    mbuf->pkt_len = mbuf->data_len;

    // Transmit the packet
    struct rte_mbuf *pkts[BURST_SIZE];
    pkts[0] = mbuf;
    uint16_t nb_tx = rte_eth_tx_burst(port_id, 0, pkts, 1);

    if (nb_tx < 1) {
        rte_pktmbuf_free(mbuf);
        printf("Failed to send packet\n");
    } else {
        printf("Packet Sent\n");
    }
}

void initialize_dpdk(int argc, char **argv) {

    int ret;
    ret = rte_eal_init(argc, argv);
    if (ret < 0) {
        rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Error with EAL initialization\n");
    }

    // Configure Ethernet port
    uint16_t port_id = 0;
    struct rte_eth_conf port_conf = port_conf_default;
    struct rte_eth_dev_info dev_info;

    rte_eth_dev_info_get(port_id, &dev_info);

    port_conf.rxmode.mtu = RTE_MIN(
                    dev_info.max_mtu,
                    port_conf.rxmode.mtu);

    ret = rte_eth_dev_configure(port_id, 1, 1, &port_conf);
    if (ret < 0) {
        rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot configure device: err=%d, port=%u\n", ret, port_id);
    }

    ret = rte_eth_rx_queue_setup(port_id, 0, 128, rte_eth_dev_socket_id(port_id), NULL, rte_pktmbuf_pool_create("RX_POOL", NUM_MBUFS, MBUF_CACHE_SIZE, 0, RTE_MBUF_DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE, rte_socket_id()));
    if (ret < 0) {
        rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot setup RX queue: err=%d, port=%u\n", ret, port_id);
    }

    ret = rte_eth_tx_queue_setup(port_id, 0, 512, rte_eth_dev_socket_id(port_id), NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot setup TX queue: err=%d, port=%u\n", ret, port_id);
    }

    ret = rte_eth_dev_start(port_id);
    if (ret < 0) {
        rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "Cannot start device: err=%d, port=%u\n", ret, port_id);
    }

    rte_eth_promiscuous_enable(port_id);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int ret;


    initialize_dpdk(argc, argv);

    send_udp_packet(0, "192.168.1.20", 12345); 

    return 0;
}

Simple C/C++ UDP receiver application
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdio_ext.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int sockfd,optval = 1;
    struct sockaddr_in server,client;
    socklen_t size = sizeof(client);
     char recvbuf[20];
   sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
   if(sockfd<0)
  {
    perror("socket");
    return 0;
  }

  server.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server.sin_port = htons(12345);
  server.sin_addr.s_addr =inet_addr("192.168.1.20");

   if(setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&optval,sizeof(optval)) < 0)
  {
   perror("setsockopt:");
   exit(0);
  }

  if(bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server)) < 0)
  {
    perror("bind");
    return 0;
  }

   while(1)
   {
   if(recvfrom(sockfd,recvbuf,20,0,(struct sockaddr*)&client,&size) < 0)
   {
       perror("recvfrom");
       exit(0);
   }
   printf("Recv data: %s\n",recvbuf);
   }
}

Wireshark captured packet image
1
2

What does Wireshark tell you?

Thanks for your reply, Please find the wireshark captured packet image in my post

Your checksum calculation makes no provision for byte order. UDP silently drops packets with incorrect checksum.

Without seeing the code of the DPDK application in question, potential readers of the OP have no way of knowing.

How are packets constructed by the DPDK application?
Does it include proper Ethernet/IPv4/UDP headers?
Which destination MAC address is used?
Does it match that of the receiver?

The best educated guess here might be receiver rejecting packets based on destination MAC address. See if you can't bypass this by enabling promiscuous mode on the receiver's network interface.

Thanks for your reply, Please find the attached code & wireshark captured image in my post.
